# sending email without authendication in android

Tags: android, email, jakarta-mail

```
     public void successSending()
     {
         String server = "smtp.gmail.com";
         String port = "465"; 
         String to = "xxxx@gmail.com";
         String from = "yyyy@gmail.com";
         Properties properties = System.getProperties();
         properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
         properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
         properties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
         properties.put("mail.smtp.host", server);
         properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port);        
         Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

      }
```

here i didn't send the email.please help to fix this issues.

Comment: Sending message along with from,to,subject and body of the message  Transport.send(message);

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
    private void sendEmail() {
    // Setup the recipient in a String array
    String[] mailto = { "tets@gmail.com" };

    // Create a new Intent to send messages
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    // Add attributes to the intent
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, mailto);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "test");

    sendIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
    startActivity(sendIntent);

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i want to send the mail without using default app and without authentication

Comment: You need a mail server that will let you send without authentication.  Gmail won't let you do that.  Most servers won't, otherwise spammers would use them all the time.